# Add points to D3 chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I was trying to add points to this chart http://bl.ocks.org/nsonnad/4175202

```
countryEnter.selectAll("dot")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("r", 3.5)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.year); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.name); });
```

But it is didn't work https://plnkr.co/edit/ADuZkJQrq7mjZqDZwrBe
May be someone can help?

Answer (score 1):

When working with a nested selection, your [data](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data) call can return a part of the data.  In this case the `values` array:

```
countryEnter.selectAll("dot")
  .data(function(d){
    return d.values; //<-- return just the values of your larger data-binding
  })
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("r", 3.5)
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.year); })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.stat); });
```

Updated [code](https://plnkr.co/edit/X85Oluvi27MoTJiB8h0m?p=preview).